# New Input class can't use Focus and Blur events

Tags: javascript, css, focus, blur

I've been having this issue lately and I couldn't seem to find an answer either here nor Google so I figured I might as well ask on my own for once. That said, I'm apologizing in advance if I misstagged this question since I genuinely can pinpoint precisely where my issue is. Also, I'm going to talk a lot about PouchDB and its tutorial not because its the issue, but because it gives a lot of context to what I'm doing.

A few weeks ago I stumbled upon PouchDB and I found its functions to be exactly what I needed for my database projects, I implemented its tutorial ([the todo's list](https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html)) with little trouble and figured the next step would be to do some tinkering with it as a base for a future, hypothetical, actual project. My knowledge about Javascript is very basic but I could do a form or a grid/list so I figured it wouldn't be that hard.

My very first idea was, instead of having a todo list, it could be a list with names of people! Just as an excuse to have two (and possibly multiple) input fields instead of the one the example code uses. Said example uses a very simple interface, in order to edit one of the todo's the user has to doubleclick the item on the list and an input field appears (the app automatically focuses on said field) where the user can rewrite or delete the item, simply pressing enter or removing the focus from the field triggers the blur event which saves its changes. The very first weird issue I ran into was that when adding a second item to edit I couldn't use the same css class as the first one.

```
  function nameDblClicked(todo) {     
    var div = document.getElementById('li_' + todo._id);
    var inputEditName = document.getElementById('input_' + todo._id);
    div.className = 'editing';
    inputEditName.focus();
  }

  function lastDblClicked(todo) {     
    var div = document.getElementById('li_' + todo._id);
    var inputEditLast = document.getElementById('input_' + todo._id);
    div.className = 'editing';
    inputEditLast.focus();
  }

//a few lines ahead on the code we make the list
  var inputEditName = document.createElement('input');
  inputEditName.id = 'input_' + todo._id;
  inputEditName.className = 'edit';
  inputEditName.value = todo.name;
  inputEditName.addEventListener('keypress', nameKeyPressed.bind(this, todo));
  inputEditName.addEventListener('blur', todoBlurred.bind(this, todo));

  var inputEditLast = document.createElement('input');
  inputEditLast.id = 'input_' + todo._id;
  inputEditLast.className = 'edit';
  inputEditLast.value = todo.lastname;
  inputEditLast.addEventListener('keypress', lastKeyPressed.bind(this, todo));
  inputEditLast.addEventListener('blur', todoBlurred2.bind(this, todo));

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = 'li_' + todo._id;
  li.appendChild(divDisplay);
  li.appendChild(inputEditName);
  li.appendChild(inputEditLast);
```

This didn't work, after a bit of research I found out that for some reason using the same css class (once again, sorry if I misused the tag) for both inputs would only let me edit the first one, so I used a bit of ducktape and just made clones of the classes on the css file: edit2 and editing2. This one actually worked! (even if I don't quite like the way I went around it, I figured I'd concern myself with that later) I could edit both fields just fine, but now I'm finally getting at the problem at hand. For some reason now the focus event on the last name field doesn't work anymore. The blur effect's didn't work either!

I tried to do some research of my own, I found out about tabindex's and how such a thing could influence on this sort of thing but adding it to the lastname field didn't do anything. I found out about set timeouts, and how for some reason the browsers might need some milliseconds to properly activate the events, that didn't work either (i tried with very large timers just to test, and the timer does work, but the focus event still doesn't trigger). I found out about how multiple browsers have different ways of doing things and how some might not posses all the functions I use, but I'm using Chrome (since I plan to have anything I come up with working on Android phones) so I figured that wouldn't be a problem, I could be wrong but I hope that's not the case. I also tried having multiple 'input' classes since having a singular edit class caused me problems but that one seemed to trigger a different kind of issue (now I couldn't access nor edit the last name field at all).

So I've been scratching my head during the last few days, besides the use of other css classes for the two inputs I can't tell the difference between the first and last name fields and why would the events work on one field and not in the other. Is this an error on my (admittedly poor) attempt to copy/paste Javascript? Are the new css classes not allowed to have those events unless I specify it somehow? Am I making a mistake by using just plain old Javascript instead of JQuery (my Google searches told me a lot of people who ran into similar issues use the later)?

Answer (score 0):

Things I noticed while creating this snippet:

`inputEditName.id = 'input_' + todo._id;`

and

`inputEditLast.id = 'input_' + todo._id;`

Appear to be assigning the same id, so one would not work.

Here's an example which I think illustrates what you kind of want.

```js
function nameKeyPressed(todo) {     
    return function(e){
      console.log('name Keypressed!')
      var div = document.getElementById('li_' + todo._id);
      var inputEditName = document.getElementById('input_first' + todo._id);
      div.className = 'editing';
      inputEditName.focus();
    }
  }

  function lastKeyPressed(todo) {     
    return function(e){
      console.log('last KeyPressed!')
      var div = document.getElementById('li_' + todo._id);
      var inputEditLast = document.getElementById('input_last' + todo._id);
      div.className = 'editing';
      inputEditLast.focus();
    }
  }

//a few lines ahead on the code we make the list
  var todo = {
    _id:'123',
    name:'firstName',
    lastname:'lastName'
  };
  var inputEditName = document.createElement('input');
  inputEditName.id = 'input_first' + todo._id;
  inputEditName.className = 'edit';
  inputEditName.value = todo.name;
  inputEditName.addEventListener('keypress', nameKeyPressed(todo));
  // inputEditName.addEventListener('blur', todoBlurred.bind(this, todo));

  var inputEditLast = document.createElement('input');
  inputEditLast.id = 'input_last' + todo._id;
  inputEditLast.className = 'edit';
  inputEditLast.value = todo.lastname;
  inputEditLast.addEventListener('keypress', lastKeyPressed(todo));
  // inputEditLast.addEventListener('blur', todoBlurred2.bind(this, todo));

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = 'li_' + todo._id;
  // li.appendChild(divDisplay);
  li.appendChild(inputEditName);
  li.appendChild(inputEditLast);
  var list = document.getElementById("ul_list");
  list.appendChild(li);
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <ul id="ul_list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I only have the mornings to do this. Anyway, this would work in the sense that it restores all the functions I lost on my last attempt, but this reverts me back to the original problem I had. Using the 'edit' and 'editing' css classes for both inputs  makes it so if I double click in either the first or the last name both fields appear, I wanted to make it so only the relevant field becomes active. Sorry, I should have probably mentioned that on the opening post.